# Using Editorial Manager webpage & a password manager (and similar pages with logins that have multipled accounts)

Tags: firefox, browser, passwords, password-management

Editorial Manager (EM) is common software that academic journals use to manage submission, review and judgements on manuscripts.

You don't have one EM login, however. You have (at least) one login per journal that uses it. I say at least, as for the same journal the same person can have separate submitter, review and editor login credentials.

So I might have dozens of EM login credentials associated with my role {submitter/reviewer/editor} at different journals.

Here is the gotcha. The URLs for the these login pages are all of the form

```
  https://www.editorialmanager.com/{abbreviated journal code}
```

and my password manager shows me all of my EM logins, regardless of which specific journal using EM software I am trying to login to. Presumably this happens because all EM journals start with `https://www.editorialmanager.com/` This issue is notorious, and (genuinely) many people just reset their password at every login.

Is there anyway round this with Firefox's default password manager? or failing that, another browser or password manager?

Comment: You can't specify a longer or more specific URL path in your password manager? If you cannot, then your only solution is a different password manager. I'm able to specify "folders" in BitWarden's password manager, but I believe it'll still show all the matches at the domain level. Another way is to label the different accounts, so you'll see all of them in the manager's list, but you'll be able to select the one appropriate for the journal you're trying to sign in to.